Prefix-free binary codes with costs
I came across the following problem:
We would like to generate n prefix-free binary codes such that we pay 4 units for each 1-bit and 1 unit for each 0-bit used. Let f(n) denote the minimal cost of generating n such binary codes. So, for example f(6) = 35 since 0000, 0001, 001, 01, 10, 11 has a total cost of 35 and there is no cheaper solution.
I need an algorithm for computing f(n) that is efficient for large values of n (up to ~10^13).
My solution was that we can assign a Huffman-like binary tree for each n that describes the cheapest solution. If we know the optimal solution for n we can find the cheapest path from the root to one of its leaves and attach a left and a right child to this leaf with codes 0 and 1. This gives the correct solution for the first few values of n, however, I am not sure whether it is correct and I did not prove it rigorously.

There is some related literature.  E.g. look at https://doi.org/10.1137/S0097539794268388 and https://doi.org/10.1137/100794092 and references cited by those.

In standard Huffman coding the input specifies a weight (i.e. frequency or probability) for each codeword, and the optimal solution depends on those weights.   Your post doesn't mention weights.   Are you assuming the weights are uniform?  If so one of the references above gives a fast algorithm for your problem.
